# Creating TUN device for IPSEC

Tags: security, tunnel, ipsec

Is it possible to create a separate device (like tun made by openvpn) for ipsec? If yes how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.
Exactly how to do this will depend on your situation.

Here's a bare-bones way to do it:

Load the kernel module.

```
/sbin/modprobe tun
```

Create the tunnel device

```
cd /dev
sudo MAKEDEV tun
```

This will create `/dev/net/tun` .

Use openvpn to create tun0 .

```
sudo openvpn --mktun --dev tun0
```

Optionally, edit `/etc/network/interfaces`, and bring up tun0 .

```
sudo ifup tun0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the OP is asking about IPsec VPN, not openVPN. As far as I can tell, IPsec binds a virtual IP to the outbound NIC(eth0, wlan0) as a secondary IP.